# Max columns in html table

Tags: html

what is the max. no of columns and rows in a html table? Are there any browser issues while viewing the table?

Comment: If you are thinking about MAX number of columns and rows in a html table, I think you need to redesign your application. Just my 0.02$

Comment: i just want to know what is the max no. of columns and rows that can be added in an html table??

Answer (score 2):

No. There is no as such limit to rows & columns. But

1. It will definitely add horizontal & vertical scroll to your page. Too much scrolling can make your page practically impossible to view.
2. Also your page size will increase a lot causing performance issue.
3. Use will loose interest in your page, due to too much contents & bad user experience

Comment: Ya definately it will be cumbersome but if user requirement is such, like if there is a customizable table for which no of rows and columns need to be entered by user and if the user enters big nos..

Comment: You can limit user for max no.

Answer (score 0):

Trawling the DOM with Javascript would adversely effect page performance, case depending.

Answer (score 0):

If it's worth asking then it's worth testing it out, pick a big number and see if you crash your browser:

```js
var t = document.getElementById('t')
var n = document.getElementById('n')
function cols(){
  t.innerHTML = '<tr>'+'<td>x</td>'.repeat(n.value)+'</tr>'
}
function rows(){
  t.innerHTML = '<tr><td>x</td></tr>'.repeat(n.value)
}
```

```html
<input id="n" placeholder="How many? / Wie viele?"/>
<button type="button" onclick="rows()">Make rows</button>
<button type="button" onclick="cols()">Make cols</button>
<table id="t">
</table>
```

Don't pick a big number unless you don't have any important stuff open.

Add your high score as a comment :)